# Nested attributes not saving when updating object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have been stuck on trying to fix an issue I am having updating a model with two levels deep of nested fields.

I have a pretty simple model

```
class Flight < Plan
  attr_accessible :travels_attributes
  has_many :travels, :class_name => "FlightTravel", :foreign_key => "plan_id", :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :travels, :allow_destroy => true
End

class FlightTravel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :segments_attributes

  has_many :segments, :class_name => "FlightSegment", :dependent => :destroy, :foreign_key => "flight_travel_id"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :segments, :allow_destroy => true
end

class FlightSegment < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Now when I try to call flight.update_attributes(:travels_attributes => {...})  in the console will update the object correctly with the right values.

I call flight.save and it doesn't do anything, and for some reason just skips updating the nested associations.  What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are there any validations that might be failing?  It would also help to see actual calls that fail, perhaps with simplified data.  Your call to update_attributes in the console should save to the database.  I assume the use of :travel_attributes[sic] as a key is a typo.

Comment: Yea sorry should have been travels_attributes.  Have updated.  Na not validation,  because it doesn't even hit the before_validation callback on the FlightSegment class

Comment: Can you do this in the rails console and then see if flight.errors is empty after #save?

Comment: p.errors # @messages=#<OrderedHash {}>

Comment: It is like as if active record is skipping the updates to the nested object because it thinks it hasn't been updated.  If I make a change to the Flight object, and then save, it will update it

Comment: I copied your code into a new rails project and found that ` p = FlightPlan.new; p.update_attributes :travels_attributes => [{:name => "foo"}]` saves both objects to the database as expected.  Does this not work in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out the problem I was having.

I had my classes actually laid out like this

```
class Flight < Plan
  attr_accessible :travels_attributes
  has_many :travels, :class_name => "FlightTravel", :foreign_key => "plan_id", :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :travels, :allow_destroy => true
End

class Travel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :segments_attributes
   has_many :segments, :class_name => "TravelSegment", :dependent => :destroy, :foreign_key => "flight_travel_id"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :segments, :allow_destroy => true
end

class FlightTravel < Travel
  attr_accessible :segments_attributes

  has_many :segments, :class_name => "FlightSegment", :dependent => :destroy, :foreign_key => "flight_travel_id"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :segments, :allow_destroy => true
end

class FlightSegment < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

I was expecting the FlightTravel segments to override the Travel segments, but for some reason it doesn't.   It works for creating records but not when you want to update.